# Convert.ToDouble and Double.Parse in C#

Tags: c#, resharper

I'd like to ask about `Convert.ToDouble` and `Double.Parse` in C#
When I write this code, it's ok

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double red;
        Console.Write("Red = ");
        red = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

but if I try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double red;
        Console.Write("Red = ");
        red = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

I get caution from ReSharper `'Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute'`
How to fix that?

Comment: What compiler options do you use to see that warning?

Comment: That sounds like a ReSharper warning.

Comment: Yes, it's not really warning, it's a caution from ReSharper.

Comment: If you want to be on the safe side, use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3s27fasw.aspx) and remember that in some cultures the decimal separator is `,` while in others it's `.` and be aware of other pitfalls of different ways to express numbers.

Comment: @Corak thanks a lot, i will have this pitfalls in view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`double` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) which cannot be `null`.

[`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) will try to parse a `string` into a `double`. It does not try to coerce mismatched values such as `null`.

[`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx) will try to take mismatched strings and find a suitable value. For `null` that would be `0.0`.

To check if a sting is directly parsable try using [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) with the appropriate overload.

For example:

```
double red;
Console.Write("Red = ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();

if(!double.TryParse(input, out red))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
}
```

This will try to parse a double using the current [Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) and default [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur explanation! But what I should add if I want to use `double.Parse` in my code?

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToDouble` is utility method.

`Convert.ToDouble` documentation explains:

> Return Value Type: System.Double A double-precision floating-point
>   number that is equivalent to value, or zero if value is null.

`Double.Parse` will throw `ArgumentNullException` if you pass null, since `Double` cannot be constructed with `null`. Explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx